# Jinja2 If Statement

Tags: python, jinja2

The code below is a sample form I'm using to learn jinja2.  As written, it returns an error saying that it doesn't recognize the {% endif %} tag.  Why does this happen?

```
<html>

Name: {{ name }}
Print {{ num }} times
Color: {{ color }}
{% if convert_to_upper %}Case: Upper
{% elif not convert_to_upper %}Case: Lower{% endif %}




{% for repeats in range(0,num) %}
{% if convert_to_upper %}
{% filter upper %}
{% endif %}
<li><p style="color:{{ color }}">{{ name }}</style></li>
{% endfilter %}
{% endfor %}
</html>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you have your lines mixed up. Your `endif` comese before `endfilter` whereas `if` is before `filter`. That's just a syntax error.